# Possible linear time algorithm for minimum xor route through array

Tags: algorithm, language-agnostic, greedy

I was asked this question during an technical interview of a big company. 
I could get to a basic brute forcing solution but was asked to find a better solution (O(n)) since n was told be within limit of 5,00,000.

Given an integer array of positive numbers (p1,p2,.. pn), the task is to find a minimum cost route from first number to last number. The route cost is defined as the summation of XOR's through the array. Example if route is p1,p4,p6,p10 then the route cost is (p1 xor p4) + (p4 xor p6) + (p6 xor p10). Revisiting any number is allowed. We have to find a minimum cost route from p1 to pn. (n<5,00,000)

I could only give a solution that was a brute force approach but it seemed very naive. The interviewer kept asking for some better solution. I was thinking about some greedy approach but couldn't get to the solution. Can you please help me.

Comment: What do you mean with "Given an integer array of positive numbers (p1,p2,.. pn), the task is to find a minimum cost route from first number to last number". What is to be found? pn? That is just the integer at the end of the array (so length n) and in a (modern) programming language you can just get the length/size of an array. So what is the unknown/what is missing in this question?

Comment: @NorbertvanNobelen The question is pretty simple, I am updating the question with one example. We have to find minimum cost path from p1 to pn choosing any number of hops. And the cost of path is summation of xor of both numbers of each hop. I am sorry if it's still not clear. The example will make it clear.

Comment: xor satisfies the triangle inequality, so why not just hop directly from first to last?

Comment: (This is a terrible interview question btw.)

Comment: Going from p1 directly to pn is the first answer that comes to mind, and since it turns out this is the best possible solution , the qeustion is really just to prove it, not to find any algorithm to achieve a lower cost. So it's a trick question.

Comment: Do not forget to mention that this "interview question is an ongoing competition" on hackerrank.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because this is an ongoing competition on hackerrank.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat this is an ongoing competition question by the way (so the story is a lie).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have the triangle inequality

```
(a XOR b) <= (a XOR c) + (c XOR b) for all a, b, c >= 0,
```

which can be proved directly by summing over bit positions or by observing that we can embed XOR as a metric in an L1 space where the `i`th dimension of the point corresponding to `a` is `2^i` if the corresponding bit in the binary representation of `a` is `1`, and `0` if the corresponding bit is `0`.

Accordingly, the best path goes straight from the first element to the last with no intermediate stops.